# Working with pandas dataframes for stock backtesting exercise

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to apply a long set of conditions and operations onto a pandas dataframe (see the dataframe below with VTI, upper, lower, etc). I attempted to use apply, but I was having a lot of trouble doing so. My current solution (which works perfectly) relies on a `for` loop iterating through the dataframe. But my sense is that this is an inefficient way to complete my simulation. I'd appreciate help on the design of my code.

> ```
> VTI    uppelower  sell  buy        AU     BU     BL      date    Tok order
> 44.58  NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-15  5  0
> 44.29  NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-18  5  1
> 44.42  NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-19  5  2
> 44.88  NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-20  5  3
> 45.24  NaN NaN  False   False   False   False   False   2001-06-21  5  4
> ```

If I wanted to run a bunch of conditions and `for` loops like the below and run the function below (the get row data function) only if the row meets the conditions provided, how would I do so?

My intuition says to use `.apply()` but I'm not clear how to do it within this scenario. With all the if's and `for`-loops combined, it's a lot of rows. The below actually outputs an entirely new dataframe. I'm wondering if there are more efficient/better ways to think about the design of this simulation/stock backtesting process.

Get row data simply obtains key data from the dataframe and computes certain information based on globals (like how much capital I have already, how many stocks I have already) and spits out a list. I append all these lists into a dataframe that I call the portfolio.

I've given a snippet of the code that I've already made using a `for`-loop.

```python
 ##This is only for the sell portion of the algorithm
 if val['sell'] == True and tokens == maxtokens: 
        print 'nothign to sell'


if val['sell'] == True and tokens < maxtokens: 
    print 'sellprice', price

    #CHOOSE THE MOST EXPENSIVE POSITION AND SELL IT#
    portfolio = sorted(portfolio, key = lambda x: x[0], reverse = True)
    soldpositions = [position for position in portfolio if position[7] == 'sold']
    soldpositions = sorted(portfolio, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)


    for position in portfolio:

        #Position must exist 
        if position[9] == True:
            print 'position b4 sold', position

            #Position's price must be LOWER than current price 
            #AND the difference between the position's price and current price must be greater than sellbuybuffer
            if abs(position[0] - price) <= sellbuybuffer:
                print 'does not meet sellbuybuffer' 

            if position[0] < price and abs(position[0] - price) >= sellbuybuffer:
                status = 'sold'

                #This is if we have no sold positions yet 
                if len(soldpositions) == 0:

                   ##this is the function that is applied only if the row meets a large number of conditions
                   get_row_data(price, date, position, totalstocks, capital, status, tokens)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas allows you to filter dataframes efficiently using boolean formulas.

Instead of using a `for` loop and conditional branching, use the following syntax:

```
df = portfolio[(portfolio['sell'] == True) & (portfolio['Tok'] < maxtokens)]
```

To sort a dataframe, you can also simply write:

```
portfolio = portfolio.sort('VTI', ascending=False)
sold_positions = portfolio[portfolio['BL'] == True].sort('upperlower', ascending=True)
```